# \floatfoot and equations

Tags: math-mode, equations, captions, floatrow

I am using `\floatfoot` to creates notes for a figure in a paper. I would like to include an equation in the notes for this figure. Specifically, I am trying to use the following code:

```
\floatfoot{Notes: The figure shows coefficients from the following specification:
$$ y = \alpha + \beta X $$
where $y$ is an outcome.}
```

When I compile this code, the PDF looks correct, although I get several errors in TeXnicCenter. I get errors like,

```
! Missing $ Inserted
```

where there are clearly no issues with a missing $ in the above code.

I was wondering if anyone has any recommendations to avoid getting these errors in TeXnicCenter. I've also tried to use the `align` and `equation` environments in the `\floatfoot` command and this generates different (but obviously still problematic) errors.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't use `$$ ... $$` anyway (see e.g. [Why is \\[ ... \\] preferable to $$ ... $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)). Using inline math isn't an option? I.e. `$ y = \alpha + \beta X $`.

Comment: The problem with inline math $ y = \alpha + \beta X $ is that the text looks pretty cluttered at that point. My equation is actually a good amount longer than my example illustrates. The entire equation takes up more than a line by itself. So, I wanted to use something like \begin{equation} to set off the text by indenting, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the equation in a `\parbox` or put the whole `\floatfoot` contents in a `minipage` as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\floatbox{figure}{\caption{Caption}}
  {\rule{2cm}{2cm}
  \floatfoot{Notes: The figure shows coefficients from the following
  specification:\endgraf
  \parbox{\linewidth}{%
  \begin{displaymath}
    y = \alpha + \beta X 
    \end{displaymath}}\endgraf
  where $y$ is an outcome.}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\floatbox{figure}{\caption{Caption}}
  {\rule{2cm}{2cm}
  \floatfoot{%
  \begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
    Notes: The figure shows coefficients from the following
    specification:
  \begin{displaymath}
    y = \alpha + \beta X 
  \end{displaymath}
  where $y$ is an outcome.
\end{minipage}%
}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```